# Unwind ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to unwind a view controller when a user clicks a cell. I get the error unrecognized selector sent to instance ... The two NSLogs I inserted do not show when I click a cell, it just crashes with that error. Here is my code for the PrepareForSegue method

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSString *pointsPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"totalPoints"];
NSString *primaryPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"type"];
int primaryType = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:primaryPath];
int totalPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:pointsPath];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"classType"];

if([sender row] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Chose 0");
    if(primaryType > 0)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:0 forKey:primaryPath];
        int newPoints = totalPoints - 1;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:newPoints forKey:pointsPath];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else if (primaryType == 0)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:0 forKey:primaryPath];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }
}
else if([sender row] > 0 && [sender row] < [self.guns count])
{
    int rowNumba = [sender row];
    NSLog(@"You chose row #%i", rowNumba);
    int numberToSave = [sender row];
    if(totalPoints < 10)
    {
        if(primaryType != 0)
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger: numberToSave forKey:primaryPath];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
        else if (primaryType == 0)
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:numberToSave forKey:primaryPath];
            int newPoints = totalPoints + 1;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:newPoints forKey:pointsPath];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
    else if (totalPoints >= 10 && primaryType != 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Too many points!"
                                                        message:@"You have the maximum amount of points"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Comment: Your structure is unclear. Can you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @V2Krazy Please add some code and a picture

Comment: @abdullahShafique all the connections are made in IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your setup. First, you should never go backwards using a segue, unless you're using an unwind segue. I'm not sure if that's what's causing your problem, but that's definitely bad. Since you do a modal transition from View1 to View2, you should go back with dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, not a segue (unless, as I said you want to use an unwind). Second, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do with the tab bar controller. I think that if you want View2 to be the first tab of the tab bar controller, then the segue from View1 should go to the tab bar controller not to View2. I don't like presenting tab bar controllers modally, I think they usually should be the window's root view controller. What is the purpose of View1? Why do you have it a s the initial view controller?

Comment: Hmm is there any way to do that in IB or should I do a custom segue with dismissing it

Comment: @V2Krazy, There's really no need or advantage to do it in IB, it's easier to just use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:. If you want to do it in IB, use an unwind segue, no need for a custom one.

Comment: Thanks that was actually awesome I didn't know about unwinding (yes, it solved the tab bar issue). However, now when I click a tableView cell it doesn't call the didSelectRow method

Comment: @V2Krazy, are you using an unwind now? If so, you don't need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can use prepareForSegue:sender: instead. The sender argument will be the cell you clicked on, and you can get the indexPath from that.

Comment: Now I get "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myCell row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8956050'. If you need code, I will edit the question and provide it. I did a little debugging and put a NSLog inside "if ([sender row] == 0)" and it didn't appear before crashing when I chose that row.

Comment: @V2Krazy, a cell doesn't have a row property. You should change the method signature to:  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender and then get the row with NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row

Comment: Oh I didn't know that I'll let you know how that works when I get back home. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ok, that got rid of the error. Now though it says I select row 0 no matter what row I actually select. I didn't declare a tableView in my .h... I only linked the datasource and delegate through IB and added the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: @V2Krazy, is your controller a UITableViewController or a UIViewController? The former has a tableView property. If you're using the latter, you need to make an outlet to the table view.

Comment: +1 for being so helpful! (not sarcastic) Everything works now... Thanks!